# How to achieve dependent filters programmatically for views exposed form?

Tags: views, 8, forms, ajax

I have a requirement like Category and Sub-category should display as dependent filters. When I choose a Category next related sub-categories should show up in another field. These mapping is done in the backend by using Taxonomy.

I have tried so many options but no success till now.

1) I used [Simple Hierarchical Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs): As my view is of content-datasource(solr search purpose), I am not getting option of Has Taxonomy Terms(Depth) option also. So this module is not working out for my scenario.

2) I referred some links related to it and tried to do it in `mymodule_form_alter` but no success.

[Link1](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/ajax-forms#debugging_ajax_callback_functions) 
[Link2](https://bouteillenicolas.com/fr/blog-drupal/views-ajax-dynamic-dependent-exposed-filters)

3) Below code I tried:

```
// Not calling Ajax function itself
    if (isset($form['field_categories'])) {
      $form['field_categories']['widget']['#ajax'] = array(
          'callback' => 'myAjaxCallback',
          'event' => 'change',
          ],
      );
    }
```

If is there any way I can add Has Taxonomy Term depth in Content-datasource view? I tried to add fields from the search api configuration page but there also that option is no there.

Can anyone help me how I can achieve that?